# XCode 8 XIB Autoresizing issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have older code, written for iOS 6. I need to implement it for iOS 10 with some new SDK. I have some XIB's. Everything was working perfectly when I was changing them. But in one XIB, when I try to change Image in my Interface Builder of UIImageView, whole layout just collapses. I have 2 views, called TopBar and Content. When I try to change just background image of TobBar View, Content view just collapses, actually, TableView in Content View just goes off the screen on the right and you can scroll to right to see content of a cell. Everything is shifting in my Content View to the right. In my XIB, image view is shifted, TableView is so big to the right. When I place everything as it was, sam thing is happening after build. I have been reading for some time now, and changing from XCode 8 to XCode 7.x in my IB does not work, layoutIfNeeded does not work. Does anyone knows what's the problem? Code still uses Autoresizing masks.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone in same situation as me: in XCode 7 it is working. So, I draw in XCode 7, and build in XCode 8, but I need to build for like 8 times, when it fixes itself. I have reported a bug to Apple.